# adding and freeing a 2d array through a function in c

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

So I ve made 2 functions to add elements to a 2d array and then to free it. The array is n x 2. I am using realloc to allocate extra space every time n=n+1. This is my code:

```
void add_cell(int** table, int value1,int value2,int elements_count){

    table=(int**)realloc(table, sizeof(*table) * (elements_count+1)); //<--I think this may be problematic
    table[elements_count]=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(table[elements_count]));

    table[elements_count][0]=value1; 
    table[elements_count][1]=value2;
}

void reset_table(int** table,int elements_count){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<elements_count;i++){
        free(table[i]);
    }
    printf("reset done");
}
```

when I am adding extra cells, I only add 1 extra row each time. so a 2x2 array becomes a 3x2 and a 3x2 becomes a 4x2, so if I am calling like this:

```
add_cell(coord_table,5,4,3);

before        after
1 2            1 2 
2 3     ->     2 3 
3 4            3 4 
               4 5
```

This is how I am calling the functions(this code does have any purpose, its just for testing the functions):

```
int main(){
    int **coord_table;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        add_cell(coord_table,i+1,i+2,i);// should allocate 1extra row each time so 
                                        //when i=0 you should have [1 2] 
                                        //when i=2 [1 2][2 3] 
                                        //when i=3 [1 2][2 3][3 4] and so on...
    }

    reset_table(coord_table,5);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        add_cell(coord_table,i+1,i+2,i);
    }

    reset_table(coord_table,5);
    free(coord_table);

   return 0;     
}
```

I am kinda new to using 2d arrays with malloc and realloc, I dont even know if this is a good way to do what I want, but its what I came up with. But it keeps crashing when it tries to call reset_table. I believe I am allocating the table wrongly with realloc, even though it crashes when it tries to free, and not when allocating.

Any idea is helpful, thanks in advance :)

Comment: sizeof(table) represents what I already have and I need something extra for the 1 extra pointer that I am adding, right? shouldnt that be sizeof(int*)?

Comment: In `add_cell()`, in the `realloc` statement, `sizeof(table)` might not return what you're expecting i.e. size of the array

Comment: I edited the post a bit and added a few notes, maybe you will understand better what I am trying to do

Comment: OT: regarding: `table=(int**)realloc(table, sizeof(*table) * (elements_count+1));`  1) Do not set the target pointer directly from the returned value from `realloc()` because `realloc()` can fail, then the target pointer would be overlayed with `NULL` resulting in a unrecoverable memory leak.  Rather, set a 'temp' variable, check (!=NULL) that temp variable. And only if not NULL, then assign to the target pointer. 2) The returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: OT: Regarding; ` table[elements_count]=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(table[elements_count]));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer. Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `free(table[i]);`  the variable: `table` is a pointer to a pointer, Suggest using; `free( (*table)[i] );`

Comment: regarding: *sizeof(table) represents what I already have*  No, that represents the size of the **, which is the size of a pointer.  (typically 4 or 8 bytes depending on the underlying architecture)  What you really want is `sizeof( int* ) * number of entries already in the table. and the new size would be the same code +1 for the new entry

Comment: in the `add_cell()` function, this statement: `table[elements_count][0]=value1;` indicates that each entry in the table is an array of `int`.  So there should be a `struct` for a single table entry where that struct contains all the fields within a single table entry.  Once you have that struct, it becomes much easier to call `malloc()`, `realloc()`, etc

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem

Comment: @ user3629249 Wow thats a lot of comments :) thx for taking the time. I solved the probem with @chux if u check the conversation bellow. Sorry for such a late reply, still trying to fix the rest of my project :) but its getting together, I hadnt given much attention to understanding the things you mentioned and it looks like I should have. I ll look into the things you said :) thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-allocate to the size of the referenced object times the number of needed elements.  Part of the problem is bad name choice. elements_count is not the count of elements, but the index of the last element.

No need for the casts.

The reallocated `table` need to be returned, else `main()` will not see the new value.

```
int** add_cell(int** table, int value1,int value2,int last_element_index){
    // table=(int**)realloc(table,sizeof(table)+sizeof(int**));
    table= realloc(table,sizeof *table) * (last_element_index + 1));
    // Better code would check for allocation success here.

    // table[elements_count]=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(table[elements_count]));
    table[elements_count]=malloc(sizeof *table[elements_count] * 2);

    table[elements_count][0]=value1; 
    table[elements_count][1]=value2;
    return table;
}
```

The original allocation not needed.

```
int main(void) {
  // int **coord_table=(int**)malloc(1*sizeof(int*));
  int **coord_table = NULL;

  int i;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    coord_table = add_cell(coord_table,i+1,i+2,i);
  }

  reset_table(coord_table,5);

  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    coord_table = add_cell(coord_table,i+1,i+2,i);
  }

  reset_table(coord_table,5);
  free(coord_table);

  return 0;     
}
```

---

Detail

`int** table` is not a 2D array.  It is a pointer.  [table as pointer to pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int**+table).  `int a[3][4]` is an example of a 2D array or [array 3 of array 4 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int**+table)

Comment: I think I understand what you did :) Looks like I had understood sizeof the wrong way. I think you forgot to open a bracket when u use realloc, but other than that code seems to be working perfectly . Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer man

Comment: but why does main see the freed array correctly though a void function, but it doesnt see the changed array if I use my original void add_cell? wouldnt the main pointer and the colmn-pointers point to the correct place when I use malloc and realloc in the function even after I return to main? do I lose the main pointer value couse I used realloc in the function? would the case be different if I allocated main pointer in main?

Comment: @MikeHatzak "why does main see the freed array correctly though a void function" --> Consider `void foo(int a) { a = rand%2};`  and `main() { int b = 1; while (1) {foo(b); printf("%d", b); }}` Half the time it appears `foo()` works `b`.  (IOWs, with a `void()` call did the pointer value of  main's `coord_table` change?

Comment: I think I get it, if I had a pointer that points to coord_table(pointer->coord_table) in main and I used *pointer as an argument in the function, to change and do things, would it have kept the changes in main when it returns?

Comment: @MikeHatzak Yes.  Either pass the _address_ of main's `coord_table` to `void add_cell(***table)` so that function can do `(*table) = this_or_that()` or return from `int **add_cell(**table)` so main can do `coord_table = add_cell(coord_table);`.